# How to install openshift origin on centos 6?

Tags: centos, openshift-origin

I haven't found any detailed documentation for newbies. I tried using oo install but it was asking something about brokers. What is are brokers? Should I install all the packages (python, ruby.. etc) before installing the openshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be where you need to start http://openshift.github.io/. It has everything you need to get Origin up and running.

If you want a have a basic understanding of the structure that makes up Openshift, check out https://www.openshift.com/walkthrough/how-it-works.

Comment: Thanks but I was searching for this. <br>
http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html